# How big is the Andromeda galaxy in the night sky?

Tags: size, angular-diameter

If divide the distance to the sun by its diameter, I get the number **107.517**
Likewise, if divide the distance to the moon by its diameter, I get the number **110.650**

Both numbers are quite similar which means both objects look roughly the same size in the sky.

Now, I'll do the same calculation for the Andromeda galaxy.
Distance: 2,537,000 light years
Diameter: 220,000 light years

Quotient: **11.531**

I get a number that's roughly 1/10th that of the moon.
This means that Andromeda should look almost 10 times bigger than the moon or the sun.

Is this calculation correct?
Does the Andromeda galaxy really look 10 times bigger than the moon in the night sky?

If it looks so big, why is it so difficult to see with the naked eye?